# Reducer receiving all action types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm coding my first Redux app. I'm making a new page in a quickstarter app based off of [this boilerplate set](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate). My problem is that the boilerplate app's `actionType` only has a `type` property and nothing else, while my actions need a `payload` as well. When the Redux app initializes or changes route, the action `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` is fired, which has a payload that consists of the location it's being changed to. This gets interpreted as an action with my type of payload, when it obviously isn't. The app then crashes when it tries to read the `filename` property of the router's payload, which doesn't exist there, but exists in my type.

My types look like this:

```
export type photoType = {
  filename: string,
  selected?: boolean
};

type actionType = {
  type: string,
  payload?: photoType
};
```

My reducer looks like this:

```
export default function photoContainer(state: Array<photoType> = [], action: actionType) {
  const idx = state.indexOf(action.payload);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PHOTO:
      return [action.payload, ...state];
    case REMOVE_PHOTO:
      if (idx > -1) {
        return [
          ...state.slice(0, idx),
          ...state.slice(idx + 1)
        ];
      }
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I thought Typescript was supposed to be able to tell apart between the shape of my action and some other action? How do I structure my reducer in such a way that it doesn't get destroyed by Redux's native actions?

Comment: Are you using a custom middleware or something? It's not very clear for me what exactly is happening with your approach.

Comment: Can we see the code where you are actually dispatching the action?  Also, it may be helpful to define your actions with a `union` type, which might look something like `type PhotoAction = { type: 'ADD_PHOTO', photo: PhotoType } | { type: 'REMOVE_PHOTO' } |  . . .`